# Error message not displaying in validation rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I created a validation rule on Date field in which I want today date or future date only and also it should not  blank.

This is my code:

```
AND( BFL_Date__c >= TODAY(), ISBLANK( BFL_Date__c ) )
```

I know I missed something and it's not working. I tried different ways also but still not getting error on date filed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation rule throws exception if formula evaluates `true`. You have to use `OR` instead of `AND` and check if `BFL_Date__c` field value is less then `TODAY()`

```
OR(
    ISBLANK(BFL_Date__c),
    BFL_Date__c < TODAY()
)
```

Comment: Its working for ISBLANK but it also taking past date.I only want to enter today or future date but not past.